# how to pronounce Xiphoidalgia in English

Tags: pronunciation

how to pronounce XIPHOIDALGIA in the English language due to a 
damaged Xiphoid Process in the human body

Answer (score 2):

Even though *Xiphoidalgia* isn't in the *Oxford English Dictionary*, the suffix *-algia* (medical) is, and has these pronunciations:

> Brit. /ˈaldʒ(ɪ)ə/,  U.S. /ˈældʒ(i)ə/

The entry on [*cephalalgia* on Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cephalalgia) provides a recorded pronunciation of that suffix.

Pronunciation of *xiphoid* is listed per *OED*:

> Brit.  /ˈzɪfɔɪd/,  U.S. /ˈzaɪˌfɔɪd/, /ˈzɪˌfɔɪd/

The [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=xiphoid) gives only (zĭ**ʹ**phoidʹ).

Per the transcriptions above, the /zɪ/ pronunciation seems to be the most internationally standard.

Many words ending in the suffix "-oid" that are disyllabic and have a single consonant in the middle have variable pronunciations of the vowel in the first syllable, such as *steroid, lipoid, peloid, trochoid.*

If you're not familiar with these pronunciation notations, you can follow the [*OED* pronunciation guide](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/).